# Joomla trigger event when element in field of “filelist” type is selected

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, jquery

I am struggling since a few days with following problem. Using Joomla 3.9.2x and query 3.5.1. I am trying to display a modal "window" when an item is selected in a Joomla filelist field. I tried a few triggers like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery("#jform_myfile_chzn").click(function(){
        UIkit.modal('#displayimage').show();
    });
});
```

After loading the page and the file is selected, it works. Obviously with "click", it shows "#displayimage" each time it is clicked and not only when the file is selected.

I tried a few others like "change", but I can't make it work.

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Thank you for taking the [tour]; perhaps consider telling us a little about you and your Joomla story by editing your profile.  Please continue to work at your issue.  If you discover more relevant clues, please edit your question.  If you manage to solve the issue yourself, please post an educational answer that will help future researchers with a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the event listener on the underlying hidden select field not on the chozen ui element.  The id of the select will be the same id without the _chzn suffix.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery("#jform_myfile").change(function(){
        UIkit.modal('#displayimage').show();
    });
});
```